# Wpf- Url to Bitmap Image quickly

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, I call a function `GetThumbnail()` in which the image downloaded as a byte array from the URL using `GetByteArrayFromRelPath()` and converted into `BitmapImage` by `ConvertToBitmapImage()`.

But it takes a lot of time around 13-15sec which become a big duration when I am getting 20-25 images in one time. I need to do it quickly. These are the functions and property that I am using.

```
public static byte[] GetByteArrayFromRelPath(string path)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            byte[] file = (new WebClient()).DownloadData(baseAddress + path);
            return file;
        }
        else return new byte[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public static BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}

private Task GetThumbnail(List<Model> models)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            try
            {
                model.ThumbnailBytes = GetByteArrayFromRelPath(model.ThumbnailPath);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    });
    return null;
}

public byte[] ThumbnailBytes
{
    get { return _thumbnailBytes; }
    set
    {
        _thumbnailBytes = value;
        Thumbnail = ConversionHelper.ConvertToBitmapImage(_thumbnailBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: What size are the images? What takes a long time - the download or the conversion to thumbnails?

Comment: I think you're downloading the images serially, one after the other. Have you thought about using `Parallel.ForEach` to parallelize the downloading?

Comment: The loop flow download>Convert>Download>Convert.. and each image has a size 31Kb,the downloading taking more time.No i did'nt think about this

Comment: Instead of synchronously downloading and creating the bitmaps, it might be better to directly create the BitmapImages from the source URIs. Then they would be downloaded asynchronously without blocking the UI.